# Hard time finding a logic when looping for in java

Tags: java, for-loop

I just started learning to code today and clearly I don't fully grasp the idea about looping at all. I found a quiz online where let's say I want to have a result of :

`5, 17, 65, ...`

and the  **formula** where:

**5  = 2 + 3 * 4^0**

**17 = 5 + 3 * 4^1**

**65 = 17 +3 * 4^2**

This is My code so far

```
package com.test;

import java.util.*;

public class Main {

    public static void main (String[] args){
        int a;
        a=2;


        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            System.out.print((a+3 * Math.pow(4,i))+", ");
        }
    }
}
```

and the result is

```
5.0, 14.0, 50.0,
```

which is far from what I want. Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance!

Edit: changed the

```
i <4
```

to

```
i < 3
```

because of typing error (accidentally deleted '194.0' when typing the output)

I edited it again, because I also deleted

```
a=2
```

below

```
int=a;
```

I somehow deleted it because in my original code there's some unused integer variable b and c from my trial and error during trying the code

Comment: You get that result? Sure? I would expect a compiler error instead.

Comment: Even if `a` was initialized, it's not being updated in the for loop, so how would you be getting different values upon each iteration? Are you sure that's the same code?

Comment: @OmarAbdelBari - `a` might not change, but `i` does.

Comment: The loop executes 4 times, but we only have 3 numbers printed.  Curiouser and curiouser.  Or, more likely, the information given us is incomplete.

Comment: yes the loop is executed 4 times, but I accidentally deleted a number in the output when editing. I edited so the "i < 3" now

Comment: Your code still doesn't compile, because `a` is never set.

Comment: If you actually initialized a to 2, but forgot to tell us that, then the output is what is expected from the code as written.  2+3*4^0 is 5, 2+3*4^1 is 14,  2+3*4^2 is 50.  But as observed, your code is not following the requirements as stated, because `a` is never changed.

Comment: One common method of debugging is to print the values of all the relevant variables on each iteration.  I would use that approach here, and take special note of the `a` variable.  What is its value supposed to represent?  Do the values accurately reflect that?  Why might that be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To cut this a little short, and assuming `a` is appropriately initialized to 2, this

```
        System.out.print((a+3 * Math.pow(4,i))+", ");
```

should be

```
        a = a + 3 * Math.pow(4,i);
        System.out.print(a + ", ");
```

so that you not only calculate the next term in the series, but you save its value for use in the following term.

You can write the first line as

```
        a += 3 * Math.pow(4,i);
```

if you prefer (I do).

Comment: It always makes me sad when I see people just hand the solution to the OP.  Why would you steal this learning opportunity from them?  This would be a great opportunity to give them hints and have them come to a conclusion on their own.  Even worse, you've included almost no explanation.

Comment: How much more explanation do you think is needed than *"you not only calculate the next term in the series, but you save its value for use in the following term"* ?  As for the rest, reasonable people can disagree about how far you'll get with the socratic method in any given case. "Steal" is a little hyperbolic.

Comment: yes you assumed correctly, a=2, I accidentally deleted it for the sake of 'cleaner' code when I post it.

That a += 3 * Math.Pow(4,i) works. thanks! :)